# State equation of a partition function in base 2

Tags: statistical-mechanics, partition-function

What is the impact on the state equation of a Gibbs ensemble if we change the base to 2. For example,

$$
\begin{align}
&Z=\sum_i{2^{-\beta (E_i+pdV)}} & \text{partition function} \\
&dE=TdS-pdV & \text{state equation}
\end{align}
$$

Does the change of basis changes the state equation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing this is the equivalent of changing the temperature of your system.  This can be seen just by recasting the new basis into the old basis.  First note that $$\gamma^x=(e^{\log\gamma})^x=e^{x \log\gamma},$$
where I choose $\gamma > 1$.  Hence your partition function becomes
$$Z=\sum_i{e^{-\log\gamma~\beta (E_i+pdV)}} = \sum_i{e^{-\beta' (E_i+pdV)}}.$$
Where we see it is unchanged, if we change our temperature such that $\beta' = \beta\log\gamma $.  That is $T'\rightarrow \frac{T}{\log\gamma}$.

Hence the equation of state would be
$$dE=T'dS-pdV=\frac{T}{\log \gamma}dS - pdV$$